# how to perform change feed in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want move only changed data from `CosmosDB` to `Storage account` like only the changed data that is modified or inserted can be moved. **How can I perform change feed process in cosmosDB?** .

---

Please share a link for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider having an Azure Function that is triggered when documents are added / updated in your collection and have the Azure Function output the document to blob storage.

This should scale well and would be relatively easy to implement. Here is an [`example`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/cosmos-db-function-trigger-2-min/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to read the change feed and all are described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/read-change-feed

Summary:

- Using Azure Functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-functions
- Using the Change Feed Processor on the SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor
- Using the Change Feed query/pull model on the SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-pull-model
- Using the Spark Connector if you are doing data analysis: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-java-spark-v3

It really depends on your scenario, which tool you might want to use.